# Django get_absolute_url on sitemap.xml getting NoReverMatch error

Tags: django, sitemap, mezzanine

models.py

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('abc', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

urls.py

```
from posts.views import xyz
from posts.sitemaps import PostSitemap


sitemaps = {
    'posts': PostSitemap()
}

urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^posts/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',xyz, name='abc'),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$',sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
)
```

sitemaps.py

```
class PostSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = 'daily'
    pirority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.all()
```

I have not changed the default contib/sitemaps/templates/sitemap.xml and when I browse mysite/sitemap.xml it's throwing error:

Reverse for 'abc' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug':        u'my-slug-goes-here'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: have you tried reversing the url manually from the shell? Like reverse('abc', kwargs={'slug': 'singleword'}). It's possible that the regex does not handle some characters in your slug?

Comment: Hi Paulo, something like mysite/posts/my-slug-goes-here is working fine on my template, it's only that sitemap.xml is not working, I will try what you said. Thanks!

Comment: I resolved it somehow by changing it as reverse('post:abc', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

Answer (score 0):

```
class PostSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = 'daily'
    pirority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.all()

    def location(self, item):
        return item.get_absolute_url()
```